# How to generate a Django one-time download link with expire time

Tags: python, django, apache

I am uploading files using the filefield model on media-root. Well, now I have a link like this : domain.com/media/file_name.file_extension.I'm asking about the best way to generate a one-time link with expire time from this main link for each user who clicks on file to download it.

```
class files(models.Model): 

 title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='imges')
 desc = models.TextField()
 created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
 download = models.FileField(upload_to='files')


 def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

this is my views:

```
def download(requset ,title):
    file = get_object_or_404 (files , title=title)
    try :
      file = files.objects.filter(title = title)
    except :
      raise Http404

    context ={
     'file' :file,
  }
return render( requset,'download.html',context)
```

this is my template:

```
<div class="fix download_button"><a href="{{f.download.url}}"></a></div>
```

this is my url:

```
    path('download/<str:title>/' , views.download , name='download'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [django-request-token](https://github.com/yunojuno/django-request-token).